# how's model of post request to login gmail in java

Tags: java, http-post, jira-rest-java-api

i tried to login gmail via sending post request flowwing the code:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testautologingmail;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.CookieHandler;
import java.net.CookieManager;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HttpUrlConnectionExample {

  private static List<String> cookies = new ArrayList<>();;
  private static HttpsURLConnection conn;
  private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";
  public HttpUrlConnectionExample(){
      
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        
    String url = "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth";
    String gmail = "https://mail.google.com/mail/";

    HttpUrlConnectionExample http = new HttpUrlConnectionExample();

    // make sure cookies is turn on
    //CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager());
        
    // 1. Send a "GET" request, so that you can extract the form's data.
    String page = http.GetPageContent(url);
    String postParams = http.getFormParams(page,"kiemtienol1506","vandai1507");

    // 2. Construct above post's content and then send a POST request for
    // authentication
    http.sendPost(url, postParams);

    // 3. success then go to gmail.
    String result = http.GetPageContent(gmail);
    System.out.println(result);
        conn.disconnect();
  }
  private static void getcookies(String url) throws MalformedURLException, IOException{
        CookieManager cookieManager = new CookieManager();
        CookieHandler.setDefault(cookieManager);
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        conn.getContent();
        List<HttpCookie> cookies2 = cookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        System.out.println("get cookies");
        for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies2) {
            System.out.println(cookie.getDomain());
            System.out.println(cookie.toString());
            String temp = cookie.toString();
            cookies.add(temp);
        }
        //conn.disconnect();
  }
  private void sendPost(String url, String postParams) throws Exception {

        
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    // Acts like a browser
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "accounts.google.com");
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        System.out.println("cookies String");
    for (String cookie : cookies) {
                //String[] tmp = cookie.split(":");
        conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
                System.out.println(cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
    }
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postParams.length()));

    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
        
    // Send post request
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(postParams);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + postParams);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in =
             new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
    //System.out.println(response.toString());
        //conn.disconnect();

  }

  private String GetPageContent(String url) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    conn = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // default is GET
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

    conn.setUseCaches(false);

    // act like a browser
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept",
        "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    if (cookies != null) {
        for (String cookie : cookies) {
            conn.addRequestProperty("Cookie", cookie.split(";", 1)[0]);
        }
    }
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in =
            new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    // Get the response cookies
    //setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));
        getcookies(url);
    return response.toString();

  }

  public String getFormParams(String html, String username, String password)
        throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

    System.out.println("Extracting form's data...");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

    // Google form id
    Element loginform = doc.getElementById("gaia_loginform");
    Elements inputElements = loginform.getElementsByTag("input");
    List<String> paramList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (Element inputElement : inputElements) {
        String key = inputElement.attr("name");
        String value = inputElement.attr("value");
                String id = inputElement.attr("id");
        if (key.equals("Email"))
                {
                    value = username;
                    paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
                }
        else if (key.equals("Passwd")){
                    paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
                    value = password;
                }
                else if(id.equals("Passwd-hidden")){
                    value = password;
                    paramList.add("Passwd=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
                }else
                    paramList.add(key + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTF-8"));
    }

    // build parameters list
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    for (String param : paramList) {
        if (result.length() == 0) {
            result.append(param);
        } else {
            result.append("&" + param);
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
  }

  public List<String> getCookies() {
    return cookies;
  }

  public void setCookies(List<String> cookies) {
    this.cookies = cookies;
  }

}
```

i also try to get cookies flow this line `setCookies(conn.getHeaderFields().get("Set-Cookie"));` but it's always return null String so i have to make getCookies() function.
i always receive status 200 OK. So is there any support to help me or another code can do this task.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you considered using [`HttpClient`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) ?

Comment: I removed `C#` and `Swing` tags from your question as it's not related to any of those

Comment: the important is model of post request, i dont know exactly the format to send request.